# Pre populate Core data Copy Issue

Tags: objective-c, core-data

I was pre-populating core data with an existing .sqlite with following code:

```
// Put down default db if it doesn't already exist
    NSError *error = nil;
    NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
    if (![fileManager fileExistsAtPath:[storeURL path]]) {
        NSString *defaultStorePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"xyz" ofType:@"sqlite"];
        if (defaultStorePath) {
            [fileManager copyItemAtPath:defaultStorePath toPath:[storeURL path] error:&error];
        }
    }
```

It was working up until I recently upgraded my Xcode and now it copies the .sqlite file to the desired location but not of the same size. Pre populated .sqlite file is of 4.7 MB and when it's copied there with above code it's of size 3.2 MB. And it gives following error:

```
SQLite error code:1, 'no such table: Z_METADATA'
```

Note:
It all works fine if I manually replace the .sqlite file in the documents.

Comment: were you able to find a solution for this issue? I'm facing the same issue.

Comment: @YasithaChinthaka not exactly I still face this issue on Simulator but on Device it works just fine.